# Results are not showing, only says "Commands completed successfully"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I recently started studying stored procedures in TSQL and I am using SSMS 2018. When I executed the first two stored procedures that I worked on, the results were still showing.

However, moments after, the messages window only says "Commands completed successfully", but there are no longer results shown.

See code below:

```
USE ALEX_DB --my database name
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.practice', 'P') IS NOT NULL --Identifies if there is an existing procedure
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.practice; --Drops if procedure exists
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.practice 
AS
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, TSM.TXN_DATE, 1) AS 'Transaction Date', 
    TCA.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + TCA.LAST_NAME AS 'Customer', 
    TSM.CUST_ID AS 'Customer ID', 
    TSM.TXN_NO AS 'Reference No.'
FROM TXN_SALES_MAST AS TSM
INNER JOIN TXN_CUST_ACCT AS TCA ON TCA.CUST_ID = TSM.CUST_ID

EXECUTE dbo.practice
```

When I ran the SELECT statement on its own, without it being inside a stored procedure, it displayed the results to grid. However, when I tried executing the stored procedure, SSMS no longer displays any result.

Comment: Is there a batch separator between the `CREATE` and `EXECUTE`, or are you running them in separate batches? If not, then the above will create a procedure, `dbo.practice` that infinitely calls itself.

Comment: If you ran that exact script you've created a stored procedure that runs a `SELECT` and then *tries to execute itself recursively*.

Comment: I noticed that I didn't have a separator between CREATE and EXECUTE. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: On a separate note, get into the habit of defining your length, scales, and precisions for your data types. Also, it's generally not recommended to use the syntax `{Expression} AS 'Alias'`. Single quotes (`'`) are for literal string; using them for alias, although works, can be confusing (for both new and old people to the language) and it's the only place the syntax works. `ORDER BY 'Customer ID'` would not order the data by the column aliased as `'Customer ID'`, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a stored procedure after it is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097095/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-after-it-is-created)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a stored procedure after it is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097095/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-after-it-is-created)

Comment: And other habits to develop. Don't format dates, numbers, etc. in a query. Let the display layer handle that since it is a highly personal choice. Avoid date formats with 2 digit years - lessons learned in Y2K. Schema-qualify your object names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights! will keep them in mind! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `GO` after `create procedure` block

```
USE ALEX_DB --my database name
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.practice', 'P') IS NOT NULL --Identifies if there is an existing procedure
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.practice; --Drops if procedure exists
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.practice 
AS
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, TSM.TXN_DATE, 1) AS 'Transaction Date', 
    TCA.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + TCA.LAST_NAME AS 'Customer', 
    TSM.CUST_ID AS 'Customer ID', 
    TSM.TXN_NO AS 'Reference No.'
FROM TXN_SALES_MAST AS TSM
INNER JOIN TXN_CUST_ACCT AS TCA ON TCA.CUST_ID = TSM.CUST_ID
GO -- here

EXECUTE dbo.practice
```

Comment: This won't change anything. This will still create a procedure that infinitely calls itself. `END` doesn't *end* the definition of a procedure.

Comment: @Larnu edited answer :) And yes, you are right for the first thing. Now is it correct for sure.

Comment: Hi! this worked for me, also got the hint from Larnu moments after posting my question. Thank you so much for the help! will keep this in mind :)